# Selecting and deselecting radio buttons in Plotly Dash

Tags: plotly, radio-button, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I would like to have the option of deselecting a radio-button that has been previously selected in a Dash. Any idea of how to it? This is my current code:

```
dbc.Row([
    dcc.RadioItems(id = '-lom-',
                   labelStyle={'display': 'block'},
                   options = [{'label': ' Light Optical Microscope (LOM)  for structure analysis', 'value': '-lom-'}],
                        style = {'text-align': 'left'}, className = 'dcc_compon')
                ]),
```

Once selected I am unable to unselect it:

[image: LOM]

Thank you
Best

Comment: If you want to be able to deselect I think you should go for a checkbox instead of radio buttons. "Checkboxes are similar to radio buttons, but with an important distinction: radio buttons are designed for selecting one value out of a set, whereas checkboxes let you turn individual values on and off. Where multiple controls exist, radio buttons allow one to be selected out of them all, whereas checkboxes allow multiple values to be selected." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: I think it's also better to use a checkbox instead of a radio button from a user perspective.  If you use a checkbox it signals the user that it can be selected and deselected, if you use a radio button it doesn't.

Comment: However, how can it be reactive to callbacks? I want a table to appear whenever the checkbox is selected. I am trying using Input(component_id='-lom-', component_property='n_clicks') but I can't get it to work

Comment: You're looking for the component property `value` not `n_clicks`. See the documentation here https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/input.